# What are those different color symbols when we mouseover on methods in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Suppose you have a method which returning some object. So, when you hover over that method used in some other class, **eclipse** show you a popup with the description about that method signature and what that method would return.

But, my question is there is a ***little symbol*** ahead of what is being return.
On different occasion you got different shape and color symbol.

I have a screen shots of that:

1) Green circle shape symbol

[image: Green circle shape symbol]

2) Red square shape symbol

[image: Red square shape symbol]

3) Yellow diamond shape symbol

[image: Yellow diamond shape symbol]

So,

- What is the significance of that little symbol?
- Why there is different color and shape for different different methods?
- Does that symbol give any idea about the method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The symbols next to the methods refer to the access modifiers

- What is the significance of that little symbol? 

  **Green circle** is public

  **Red square** means private

  **Yellow diamond** is protected

  **Blue triangle** means default(package) access
- Does that symbol give us any idea about the method?

  Yes, it tells us where it can be accessed from.
  For more on access modifiers: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: I thought by looking at my method that red may return null and green always return the object but thank god I asked the question here.

Answer (score 3):

Red square means the method is private.
Yellow diamond means the method is protected.
Green circle means the method is public.

Answer (score 1):

That are the same symbols as you see all over the IDE.
Which present the visibility of the element inside your app.

The visibility of an element in a java application can be:

1. Private: Red square
2. Protexted: Yellow diamond
3. Public: Green circle